# Cocoa : how do you name your init parameters for not interfering with ivars?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, coding-style

Let's begin with an example :

```
@interface myClass : NSObject {
    NSString * title;
}

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title;
```

Compiler doesn't like this because title init parameter hides myClass title ivar.

But i don't like these options :

```
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)t;
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)myTitle;
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)_title;
```

So that's a poll: what's your convention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some people prefer calling their ivars `_title` or `title_` and then they can just use `title` as parameter name in functions. Or you just call it `aTitle` or `newTitle`. There is no right or wrong way to do it.

Comment: thanks to your answer. But if I make my ivar a property, I would access by `myClass._title`... don't like so much

Comment: Not necessarily. Use `@prototype (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;` and then `@synthesize title = _title;`.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle;`.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use `pTitle`, but used `inTitle` for years.